# How can I get read/write instant speed of a Hard Drive using /proc/diskstats data?

Tags: monitoring, proc, disk, statistics, iostat

I know that the proc/diskstats file presents these data columns:

```
1 - major number
2 - minor mumber
3 - device name
4 - reads completed successfully
5 - reads merged
6 - sectors read
7 - time spent reading (ms)
8 - writes completed
9 - writes merged
10 - sectors written
11 - time spent writing (ms)
12 - I/Os currently in progress
13 - time spent doing I/Os (ms)
14 - weighted time spent doing I/Os (ms)
```

Now I want to know if there is any way to get the instant transfer rate for read and write of a hard drive.

Is it right if I divide completed reads(column 4) divided by time spent reading(column 7) to get the read instant speed? The same would happen for the writes with different columns I suppose.

In another words, I am looking for a way to calculate the amount  of  data  read  from  the  device and the  amount  of  data  written  to  the  device like on ubuntu's iostat man page(kB_read/s and kB_wrtn/s columns).

This solution seems to me like a long time average, it's not instant speed... am I right?

Waiting some hints :) thank you

Comment: First, **precisely** define what you mean by "instant transfer rate".  There are too many variables otherwise.

Comment: @AndrewHenle
I mean the amount  of  data  read  from  the  device and the  amount  of  data  written  to  the  device like on ubuntu's iostat man page(kB_read/s and kB_wrtn/s columns).